# Calling a function in a separate function file - matlab

Tags: matlab, function

From what I understood of matlab, if you want to define a function and use it in your "main file" you need to write the function in a separate file and to call it at the beginning of your "main file" with `addpath('...\myfunction.m')`.

Now let's say I define a function `f1` in a file `f1.m` that I use in `main.m`, if I want to define a function `f2` (in another file) that needs to call `f1`, can I use `addpath()...\f1.m` in my `f2.m` file ? Or what is the best way of calling `f1` in `f2` ?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do that is having your functions at same folder, or you'll need to add folder by folder.
So if you put `f1.m`, `f2.m`, `f3.m` at different folders, you have to call a `addpath` for every function.
If you have a folder 'myfunctions', all you need to do is `addpath('...\myfunctions\')`.

If you have a folder named `myfunctions` with your functions at same folder of you main script, you just have to add that folder to path.
For example:

```
%Main script
addpath('myfunctions')
x = -0.5 + rand(100,1); 
y = -0.5 + rand(100,1);
[a,b] = f1(x,y);
```

Inside the folder `myfunctions` you have the files `f1.m` and `f2.m`:

```
function [a,b] = f1(x,y)
a = x + y;
b = f2(a);
end
```

```
function b = f2(inp)
b = inp<0;
end
```

You can't use `addpath` with a file, it has to be a folder.

Comment: When I do so I get a syntax error telling that: function name f1 is known to MATLAB by its file name: 'myfunctions'

Answer (score 0):

Save all your files in the folder where matlab is opened, and you wont need addpath to explicitly tell matlab to search in the told directories for files

Answer (score -1):

You should create a startup.m file that you run at the start. located in your current directory. This should include all of your paths you need to add.

So your m file would look like :

```
startup
f1
f2
```